# Python - read from a remote logfile that is updated frequently

Tags: linux, logfile

I have a logfile that is written constantly on a remote networking device (F5 bigip). I have a Linux hopping station from where I can fetch that log file and parse it. I did find a solution that would implement a "tail -f" but I cannot use nice or similar to keep my script running after I log out. What I can do is to run a cronjob and copy over the file every 5 min let's say. I can process the file I downloaded but the next time I copy it it will contain a lot of common data, so how do I process only what is new? Any help or sugestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Two possible (non-python) solutions for your problems. If you want to keep a script running on your machine after logout, check `nohup` in combination with `&` like:

`nohup my_program & > /dev/null`

On a linux machine you can extract the difference between the two files with

`grep -Fxv -f old.txt new.txt > dif.txt`

This might be slow if the file is large. The dif.txt file will only contain the new stuff and can be inspected by your program. There also might be a solution involving `diff`.